# how to bind the same event to checkboxes, dropdown select and multiple select components?

Tags: javascript, jquery

there are checkboxes, dropdown select and multiple select components in my webform, I want that they bind the same event that will be triggered when items are check(unchecked) or selectd(unselected), show should do that? Is there a clever and neat way?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) to target all the inputs, select, buttons on your site. and then bind the .change() event.

```
$(":input").bind("change", function() {
    //What you want to happen
});
```

you can even bind more events like click depending on what oyu want to do:

```
$(":input").bind("change click", function() {
    //What you want to happen
});
```

or if you want specific inputs:

```
$("input.special, select.myFormSelect, #username").bind("change click", function() {
    //What you want to happen
});
```

Comment: you can bind multiple event like `$(":input").bind('change click select', function(){});`